# TYPO3 cache warmup with crawler not working

Tags: caching, web-crawler, typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a strange behaviour with the cache in my TYPO3 installation:

#### Situation:

- TYPO3 v9.5.22
- the cache for the page exists
- the page is only accessible for a certain *FE usergroup*
- cache is build with EXT:crawler (the configuration is setup with the needed *FE usergroup*)

#### First test

- I am logged in with a *FE user* with the needed *FE usergroup*

**Result:** 
Page needs long time on first request, runs fast on second request
→ that feels as if the cache does not exist but is build with the first request

#### Second test

- still logged in with same *FE user* from first test
- also logged in as *BE user* with activated *adminPanel*
- settings in the *adminPanel*:

  - "No cache" is not checked (so cache should be used)

**Result:**
Same behaviour as in first test, *adminPanel* → TypoScript shows that page is build (`Page generation`), so cache is **not** used

#### Third test

- all settings from second test
- settings in *adminPanel*:

  - simulate *FE usergroup* → choose the needed *FE usergroup*

**Result:**
Fast response, *adminPanel* show that cache is used.

#### My conclusion:

- cache in general works
- warm up fails *somehow* → crawler configuration might be falsy?

What can be the reasons for this behaviour?
Is my configuration falsy?
Can some other settings in TYPO3 create this situation?

Comment: Be aware of some Caches like FE-Page-Cache is bypassed when logged in the Backend from the same browser session.

Comment: I had problems with the crawler spacially with performance and stopping crawling on errors. I wrote a little bash-script that I use for warmup caches. It works automatically with configured base with multiple Sites and uses sitemap.xml for crawling. If you are interested: https://gitlab.com/tgaertner/t3warmup

Comment: But it FE-Page-Cache is bypassed, shouldn't it be slowly in both cases (second & third test) when I am logged in as BE user? In the third test it is cached...

The pages are access restricted, as I interpret your script it's not able to access those pages!?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe the adminPanel makes the difference here. And yes you are right - the script can not crawl access restricted pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was following:

- the page is access restricted with a single *FE usergroup*
- in the crawler configuration I added only the single *FE usergroup* which was needed to access the page
- the *FE user* had **two** *FE usergroups*.

The reason why the cache from the crawler is not taken into account depends on the way how TYPO3 caching works:

- TYPO3 gets **all** *FE usergroups* of a user.
- These *FE usergroups* are one of the input parameter to caculate a hash.
- This hash is an identifier. It is used to check whether a cache was already build with these parameters.
- My crawler was set up with only one *FE usergroup*  but my test user has two of them.
- That's why the hash will be different. So the cache which was created by the crawler is not taken into account.

So the solution would be: Create a crawler configuration for every possible *FE usergroup* configuration which could users have.